# Pandas .resample() method - custom label?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am a bit stuck with my use of .resample() method. I am working with a DateFrame where indexes are TimeDate objects in YYYY-MM-DD format, and I have a row of columns corresponding to property costs in a few cities, like shown below:

```
State       California  Illinois    Pennsylvania    Arizona
RegionName  Los Angeles Chicago     Philadelphia    Phoenix
1/1/2000    204400      136800      52700           111000
2/1/2000    207000      138300      53100           111700
3/1/2000    209800      140100      53200           112800
4/1/2000    212300      141900      53400           113700
5/1/2000    214500      143700      53700           114300
6/1/2000    216600      145300      53800           115100
7/1/2000    219000      146700      53800           115600
8/1/2000    221100      147900      54100           115900
9/1/2000    222800      149000      54500           116500
```

When I apply .resample() method to it to transform display into a quarterly view, I get data arrangement as follows:

```
hd = hd.resample('Q').mean()


State       New York    California  Illinois    Pennsylvania    Arizona
RegionName  New York    Los Angeles Chicago     Philadelphia    Phoenix
3/31/2000   NaN         207066.6667 138400      53000           111833.3333
6/30/2000   NaN         214466.6667 143633.3333 53633.33333     114366.6667
9/30/2000   NaN         220966.6667 147866.6667 54133.33333     116000
```

However, I need the labels on the newly created indexes to be displayed in a format resembling '2000q1' style, not the last (or first) day of the quarter.
I have been all over the .resample() method's page in pandas documentation, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to apply a custom label like that.
Can anyone help me please?

Kind regards,
Greem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
#hd.index = pd.to_datetime(hd.index)
hd = hd.resample('Q').mean()
hd.index = hd.index.to_period('q').strftime('%Yq%q')
print (hd)
State       California Illinois Pennsylvania Arizona
RegionName Los Angeles  Chicago Philadelphia Phoenix
2000q1          207066   138400        53000  111833
2000q2          214466   143633        53633  114366
2000q3          220966   147866        54133  116000
```

Comment: That's a great tip, I am still new to pandas in general, and datetime objects confuse the hell out of me. The only problem I have with your solution is that I need the 'Q' letter to be lower case, not upper case. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Oops, just noticed that you have updated your post with answer to my follow-up question before I finished editing my reply. Might thanks mate, you rock! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the index with a `period` version using `to_period` then perform a `groupby`

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.set_index(df.index.to_period('Q')).groupby(level=0).mean()

State   California Illinois Pennsylvania Arizona
Region Los Angeles  Chicago Philadelphia Phoenix
2000Q1      207066   138400        53000  111833
2000Q2      214466   143633        53633  114366
2000Q3      220966   147866        54133  116000
```

---

Or more succinctly with the `strftime` included in @jezrael's answer

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_period().strftime('%Yq%q')).mean()

        California Illinois Pennsylvania Arizona
       Los Angeles  Chicago Philadelphia Phoenix
2000q1      207066   138400        53000  111833
2000q2      214466   143633        53633  114366
2000q3      220966   147866        54133  116000
```